# cant get email with Net::Facebook::Oauth2

Tags: perl, facebook-graph-api

```
  my $fb = Net::Facebook::Oauth2->new(
        application_id => 'your_application_id',
        application_secret => 'your_application_secret',
        callback => 'http://yourdomain.com/facebook/callback'
    );

    my $access_token = $fb->get_access_token(code => $cgi->param('code'));
    ###save this token in database or session

    ##later on your application you can use this verifier code to comunicate
    ##with facebook on behalf of this user

    my $fb = Net::Facebook::Oauth2->new(
        access_token => $access_token
    );

    my $info = $fb->get(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me' ##Facebook API URL
    );

    print $info->as_json;
```

when i try to print the json format of response i am missing the email the followin is the output what i get

```
{"id":"100001199655561","name":"Pavan Kumar Tummalapalli","first_name":"Pavan","middle_name":"Kumar","last_name":"Tummalapalli","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/pavan.tummalapalli","username":"pavan.tummalapalli","hometown":{"id":"125303864178019","name":"Kodada, India"},"location":{"id":"115200305158163","name":"Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh"},"favorite_athletes":[{"id":"108661895824433","name":"AB de Villiers"}],"education":[{"school":{"id":"129163957118653","name":"City Central School"},"type":"High School"},{"school":{"id":"124833707555779","name":"Anurag Engineering College"},"year":{"id":"136328419721520","name":"2009"},"type":"College"}],"gender":"male","timezone":5.5,"locale":"en_US","verified":true,"updated_time":"2012-12-30T09:13:54+0000"}
```

'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email

the i get the following reponse as

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you do not have adequate permission to access that data. The code you provided doesn't indicate if you have requested [email permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) on authorization process so I'm guessing you didn't request it.

When you redirect your user to [Auth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/), which is like https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE&scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES , you have to specify scope=email to acquire permission to access  email field.

To check if you have the permission, you can access the URL below and see if you have it.

```
my $permission_ref = $fb->get(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions'
);
```

The returning value should be something like below.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "email": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

If it includes email, you have the permission to access user email.

If not you'll have to request permission to get it. With Net::Facebook::OAuth2, you can generate this dialog url like below.

```
  my $fb = Net::Facebook::Oauth2->new(
      application_id     => 'your_application_id', 
      application_secret => 'your_application_secret',
      callback           => 'http://yourdomain.com/facebook/callback'
  );

  my $url = $fb->get_authorization_url(
      scope => ['email'],
  );
```

Redirect your user to this url and you'll get the permission.

And even if you have email permission, sometimes email is not returned because of a bug. You might want to check this bug report, "[API call to /me is missing user's email even with email permission](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/487563591260030)."

Comment: really Thanks for replying me .. actually i got a solution after 1 hour of posting where i added scope 'email'  as u mentioned in ur solution..